# Avoiding locked SQLite database timeouts with PHP/PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm currently trying to fix an [issue in Drupal core's issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1120020) having to do with timeouts happening when someone visits a site while it is performing search indexing, a rather write-intensive operation that usually happens at the invocation of a cron command (so it's quite likely to happen on a live site while still accessible to the public). It stems from SQLite's locking on writes, which usually isn't an issue, but is in this case because doing this indexing is greatly increasing the likelihood that a connection will time out while waiting for the lock to release.

The answer seems to be to increase the amount of time that the driver waits for the lock to release. In PHP, this is supposed to be possible by setting the `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT` option to the number of seconds to wait for the lock. However, this doesn't seem to actually work; the timeouts happen no matter what value pass along this. I can't find any mention of it not working anywhere else on the internet, though, so is it just us? Has anyone else encountered trouble trying to increase SQLite's timeout time? Is there perhaps some other way we can avoid this issue happening?

Comment: Using SQLite for websites more complex than guest book/blog isn't a good idea. You should either move to another db engine or use google custom search engine for website search.

Comment: I'm not working with a single web site for which I can make decisions like that. I'm trying to fix an issue in the core of Drupal, a widely-used content management system. Removing SQLite support from the system, or telling everyone to use Google for their search needs, is both impossible and impractical. And for the record, there are many cases for which SQLite is a very good choice for a site; one that gets a lot of anonymous traffic and/or is hosted on a memory-limited VPS account, for example.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am having similar issues with PHP5 and SQlite3.

Comment: Nope, sorry. The bug is still outstanding. =/

Answer (score 3):

There is only one possible solution -

```
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, (int)$time_in_seconds);
```

Do not forget, that the time is in SECONDS :-)

Comment: PDO_ATTR_TIMEOUT does not exists, but PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT do

Comment: Be aware: Changing the timeout later on does not work. You have to set it initially when calling new PDO()

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to alleviate this by using

```
PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY; PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;
```

and using transactions when writing. It won't resolve it fully but it will make your writes much much faster, especially if it's a bunch of updates/inserts that are all done at the same time.

Comment: I am not sure that setting the journal_mode to MEMORY is a great idea.  Here is what sqlite.org had to say:  The MEMORY journaling mode stores the rollback journal in volatile RAM. This saves disk I/O but at the expense of database safety and integrity. If the application using SQLite crashes in the middle of a transaction when the MEMORY journaling mode is set, then the database file will very likely go corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Does it possible to enter read-only state while performing search indexing?
(read-only is better than timeouts...)

If so I would suggest doing it like that:

- in the application level (e.g. drupal's core code), block all write queries in a friendly way
- copy the database file
- perform the search indexing on the copied file, the main file isn't locked
- overwrite the main file with the copied file (deleting the un-needed file)
- enable write queries and back to normal state

Answer (score 1):

PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT seems to be ignored when using the following two PRAGMA commands together.  Use one or the other by itself and the timeout works as expected.  SQLite Version: 3.7.7.1

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL
```

I don't see why you would want to include both of these, but I did run into a situation where they were both used, and I was seeing the SQLite database is busy message because the timeout was not being respected.